# Logout from Facebook ios sdk objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, logout, fbsdk

i am implementing Facebook login in my ios app. Once i logout and try to login again it don't ask me the User email and password, instead it directly show a permission screen. How to make it ask the user email and password again. I have tried to logout by using login manager logout method and even setting current access token to nil, but it don't work. Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Will it solve your issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to logout from your mobile brower or Simulator browser for it.
Open Browser, Open Facebook.com and logout from your account.

If you are not logged into from your browser then It will ask for email and password.

This will solve your issue.

Comment: i am testing this  in simulator. Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: go into browser, Open facebook.com and logout from it

Comment: so is there any way to do it by any  code ?  and thank you for help